# Invoke ActiveXobject via java script - object undefined error

Tags: javascript, activexobject

All,

I have a java script file that opens a notepad file but getting undefined object error. I feel this is something to do with security but not sure.. 
Could you please advise?

Note: Calling run function on click of a button.
Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined
In IE - I am able to get alert 4 but can not see notepad but in Chrome getting stuck at alert 1 only.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function run() {
        alert("step 1");
        var oShell;
        oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
        alert("step 2");
        var commandtoRun = "c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe";
        alert("step 3");
        oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun, "", "", "open", "1");
        alert("step 4");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: In [**Microsoft's own documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/7sw4ddf8(v=vs.94).aspx) `Creating an ActiveXObject on a remote server is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 standards mode, Internet Explorer 10 standards mode, Internet Explorer 11 standards mode, and Windows Store apps or later.`

Comment: In Chrome - you are getting stuck at alert1 beacuse ActiveXObject is not supported in other browsers.   <br/>In IE - you are getting stuck at alert4 - because your browser is not having the permission to run the exe's. You get permission denied error.

Answer (score 2):

`ActiveXObject` is a proprietary Microsoft feature and is not supported in any browser other than Internet Explorer.

Other web browsers do not allow webpages to run arbitrary programs under any circumstances.

Comment: Thank you! got it ... one query though... at least in IE, I should be able to open the notepad ? if I am able to see the step 4 alert ?  Is something wrong I am doing ?